# ASP.NET MVC: View does not display updated model

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I can't get my head around this one. I have a `Html.DropDownList`, I simply want to display the value of the selected item in a `Html.Display` item.

**Model**

```
public class MyModel
{
    private List<string> _items = null;
    private string _selectedItems = string.Empty;

    public MyModel()
    {
        _items = new List<string> { "item1", "item2", "item3" };
        _selectedItems = _items[0];
    }

    public List<string> Items { get { return _items; } }

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get{ return _selectedItems; }
        set { if (_selectedItems != value) { _selectedItems = value; } }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model MyModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItem, new 
SelectList(@Model.Items), new { onchange = "SelectedItemChanged(this);" })
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SelectedItem)
```

**Controller's action**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OnSelectedItemChanged(string itemName)
    {   
        return View("Index", new MyModel { SelectedItem = itemName }); 
    }
```

I use ajax to call the controller's method - in my View, in the script section I have:

```
function SelectedItemChanged(selectObj) {
    itemName = selectObj.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("OnSelectedItemChanged","Home")',
        data: { 'itemName': itemName },
    });
}
```

The controller gets called properly but for some reason the view displayed by the browser does not get updated, and the text field still displays the initial "item1" value. How come?

I should also note that, looking in the "response" tab of the ajax request, the response html is updated correctly!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are making an ajax call, but not using the response coming back form the ajax call ! why do you expect the view in your browser to get updated ? Add `success` callback or `done` to your ajax call and update the DOM as needed.

Comment: You making an ajax call and returning a view (which should be a partial view) but not doing anything with it. You need to update the DOM in the success callback

Comment: Also why is your constructor (`DummyModel`) different from your class name ?

Comment: the whole point of ajax is to update a specific part of the page using the response from that call (or not update anything at all, if you just send data to the server). If you want to refresh the whole page, just use a regular postback